# Accelerometer problem in Galaxy S2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, sensors

In my Galaxy S2 I think that the accelerometer is not all right. When I play games like Asphalt 7 or Temple Run, the character in Temple Run and the Cars in Asphalt 7 always turn left even when my phone is straight.

I use this code `*#0*#` and `check sensor> accelerometer> image test` and it gives these results when I hold my phone horizontally and straight (not slanted):

x=25-30, y=55-60, z=9-10

(Even my auto-screen rotation does not work properly.)

I calibrated the gyroscope sensor, but it did not solve my problem.

What should I do?

(Android 4.1.2 XWLSW)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your phone Accelerometer(not Gyroscopre). If it is not a hardware problem then Try Restart your phone.
Go to "Settings"-> "Motion" -> "Sensitivity Settings" -> Calibration ->calibrate.
 It automatically calibrates the screen and the gyro sensor.

IF the problem exist, backup all your things & Restore your phone to factory settings.

NOTE : Make sure you keep the device on a flat surface and phone screen facing upwards when calibrating the sensor as it gives better results.